# Angular 9 Render data in sync in view with the values I posted to the back-end?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular9

How to render new data from the backed without refreshing the view. I'm making a post-call to the same API and I want the view to update with the new values I posted to the backend without refreshing. How to achieve this in angular 9?

Comment: If you assign the public variables that you reference inside the view it is automatically updated by Angular. Perhaps you could share a minimal example where you explain what is not clear or what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to refresh the view in order to get new data.

In angular you have two-way binding which is capable of modifying the view without refresh.

Example

**component.html**

```
<div>Your age is {{age}}</div>
```

This means that in your .ts file you have a public variable called age

**component.ts(simplified)**

```
private age:number=0;
     
public increaseAge(){
   http.post("age",number+1).toPromise().then((val)=>{
     this.number=val;
   })
}
```

This way when the api respond your local variable will be set to the value of response and angular will automatically update the html for you